# Crashed When show UIAlertView

Tags: ios, crash, uialertview

I got a crash log. It seems that When a UIAlertView is showing, My App crashed and I it is worksforme, the crash log is that

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x30288dfc
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x30288dfc __pthread_kill (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x30228909 abort (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 77
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x302b2331 szone_size (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 1
3   CoreUI                              0x2811a0b7 _freeBOMFile (in CoreUI) + 35
4   CoreUI                              0x28119da5 BOMFileNewFromFDWithSys (in CoreUI) + 245
5   CoreUI                              0x280c8c95 _BOMFileNewFromCFReadStreamSys (in CoreUI) + 25
6   CoreUI                              0x280fe6b5 __69-[_CSIRenditionBlockData expandCSIBitmapData:fromSlice:makeReadOnly:]_block_invoke (in CoreUI) + 137
7   CoreUI                              0x280fe4a7 -[_CSIRenditionBlockData expandCSIBitmapData:fromSlice:makeReadOnly:] (in CoreUI) + 391
8   CoreUI                              0x28102287 csiCompressImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions (in CoreUI) + 1107
9   CoreGraphics                        0x22763423 CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions (in CoreGraphics) + 179
10  CoreGraphics                        0x227630db img_blocks_create (in CoreGraphics) + 371
11  CoreGraphics                        0x227560a5 img_data_lock (in CoreGraphics) + 1229
12  CoreGraphics                        0x227553bb CGSImageDataLock (in CoreGraphics) + 95
13  libRIP.A.dylib                      0x22ab27b7 ripc_AcquireImage (in libRIP.A.dylib) + 623
14  libRIP.A.dylib                      0x22ab18df ripc_DrawImage (in libRIP.A.dylib) + 611
15  CoreGraphics                        0x227552c1 CGContextDelegateDrawImage (in CoreGraphics) + 45
16  CoreGraphics                        0x22755159 CGContextDrawImage (in CoreGraphics) + 269
17  UIKit                               0x259d1453 -[UIImage drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:] (in UIKit) + 1467
18  UIKit                               0x259d0e87 -[UIImage drawAtPoint:blendMode:alpha:] (in UIKit) + 99
19  UIKit                               0x25a2fdf3 -[UIImage drawAtPoint:] (in UIKit) + 39
20  UIKit                               0x259cf41b -[UIImageView _setImageViewContents:] (in UIKit) + 1179
21  UIKit                               0x259ceaf5 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] (in UIKit) + 73
22  UIKit                               0x25cc0a69 -[UIImageView _updateImageViewForOldImage:newImage:] (in UIKit) + 677
23  UIKit                               0x259ce507 -[UIImageView setImage:] (in UIKit) + 267
24  UIKit                               0x25e254d5 -[_UIAlertControllerActionView initWithFrame:] (in UIKit) + 605
25  UIKit                               0x259df275 -[UIView init] (in UIKit) + 45
26  UIKit                               0x26065c27 -[_UIAlertControllerView _prepareCancelView] (in UIKit) + 67
27  UIKit                               0x260653c7 -[_UIAlertControllerView _prepareViewsAndAddConstraints] (in UIKit) + 151
28  UIKit                               0x25d42047 -[UIAlertController loadView] (in UIKit) + 75
29  UIKit                               0x259c1f19 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] (in UIKit) + 69
30  UIKit                               0x259c1e9d -[UIViewController view] (in UIKit) + 25
31  UIKit                               0x25ca7149 -[UIViewController _setPresentationController:] (in UIKit) + 93
32  UIKit                               0x25ca2683 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] (in UIKit) + 767
33  UIKit                               0x25ca364f -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] (in UIKit) + 2851
34  UIKit                               0x25ca515b __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke (in UIKit) + 259
35  UIKit                               0x25aa1d93 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] (in UIKit) + 195
36  UIKit                               0x2605fb9f -[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow presentAlertController:animated:completionBlock:] (in UIKit) + 335
37  UIKit                               0x2605e757 -[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenter _presentAlertControllerAnimated:completion:] (in UIKit) + 191
38  UIKit                               0x25d49377 -[UIAlertView _showAnimated:] (in UIKit) + 207
39  MyApp                             0x00ff1a8b +[UIAlertView(Blocks) showConfirmationDialogWithTitle:message:cancel:confirm:handler:] (in MyApp) (UIAlertView+Blocks.m:140)
40  MyApp                             0x000d8fdb -[MyAppViewController startUpdatingLocation] (in MyApp) (MyAppViewController.m:842)
41  MyApp                             0x000d56f1 -[MyAppViewController viewDidAppear:] (in MyApp) (MyAppViewController.m:140)
42  UIKit                               0x259d789f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] (in UIKit) + 503
43  UIKit                               0x25a841b7 -[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:] (in UIKit) + 175
44  UIKit                               0x259d789f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] (in UIKit) + 503
45  UIKit                               0x259d7d63 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] (in UIKit) + 291
46  UIKit                               0x25cbd005 __97-[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:]_block_invoke749 (in UIKit) + 25
47  UIKit                               0x25a3bd7f -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] (in UIKit) + 55
48  UIKit                               0x25a3bd0d _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack (in UIKit) + 309
49  UIKit                               0x259b7c67 _afterCACommitHandler (in UIKit) + 487
50  CoreFoundation                      0x224ea5cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 21
51  CoreFoundation                      0x224e7c8b __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation) + 279
52  CoreFoundation                      0x224e8093 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 915
53  CoreFoundation                      0x22436621 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 477
54  CoreFoundation                      0x22436433 CFRunLoopRunInMode (in CoreFoundation) + 107
55  GraphicsServices                    0x2979f0a9 GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 137
56  UIKit                               0x25a21359 UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 1441
57  MyApp                             0x00011f1f main (in MyApp) (main.m:26)
```

I try to simulate low memory situation and It is still worksforme. Do you have some idea?

Comment: If you don't show the full log and related source code, it will be hard to identify the problem.

Comment: Add your code, without that can't say anything on the issue

Comment: Sorry，It is not big system，To much code to paste.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue. did you find any solution for this crash?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)addAlertView
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
    @"Title" message:@"This is a test alert" delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

    [alertView show];

}
```

hope it will help u ..

set message and buttons according to ur needs

if it not working then remove ur app from simulator & them run

Comment: Thank you, but it do not help me. And If you set a delegate to alertView, you must be careful with it, to avoid to send msg to released object.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same crash log, and the log was found on devices running iOS 7.0.4 mostly. The version before iOS 8.3 also have the issue.

After reviewing code, I found that the Class which used AlertView does not declare the UIAlterViewDelegate protocol. OC Runtime can make sure the delegate method run normally, but I think there is some unknown logic in iOS.

After I fix the bug, the crash log gone....

I think it's iOS bug which has been fix in iOS 8.3